# How can i make a random sound array with objective c?

Tags: objective-c

So i've done the tutorial where you code a button so that when you press it a sound plays. I'm trying to modify it so that when the button is pressed, a random sound plays.

here is the code:

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface STViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sounds;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "STViewController.h"

@interface STViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playAudio;

@end

@implementation STViewController


- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Woof" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];

    if (!audioError) {
        [audioPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"Woof!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

I've been dabbling with something along these lines

```
- (NSArray *)sounds
{
    NSArray *sounds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"Woof.mp3",
                       @"Meow.mp3",
                       @"tweet.mp3",
                       @"Squeak.mp3",
                       @"Moo.mp3",
                       @"Croak.mp3",
                       @"Toot.mp3",
                       @"Quack.mp3",
                       @"Blub.mp3",
                       @"OWOwOw.mp3",
                       @"Fox.mp3",
                       nil];

    return sounds;
}
```

but i'm not really sure how to make it random or even implement in in the code that I have going right now.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You'd use `random()` and "mod" it (use the `%` operator) with the size of your array, to generate an array index.

Comment: I'm sort of new at this so please bare with me.  Does that go when i'm calling the sound or setting up the array?

Comment: You use it when you pull a name of the sounds out of the array.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll keep my pants on.  (And you do too, please.)  You use the random index to, uh, index the array of sounds, to pick the "random" one to play.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it random try below:-

```
      NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray     
       arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Woof.mp3",
                   @"Meow.mp3",
                   @"tweet.mp3",
                   @"Squeak.mp3",
                   @"Moo.mp3",
                   @"Croak.mp3",
                   @"Toot.mp3",
                   @"Quack.mp3",
                   @"Blub.mp3",
                   @"OWOwOw.mp3",
                   @"Fox.mp3",
                   nil];

           // now use exchangeobject with index api
          int i=0;
      for(i=0;i<=[array count]; i++)
     {

   NSInteger rand=(arc4random() %10);
  [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i    
  withObjectAtIndex:rand];
  }
```

Comment: In this every time arc4random will print the numbers in a randomly. So  exhangeobjectatindex api will arrange mutable array elements accordingly

Comment: ok, so i've never seen arc4random before. i guess you sort of explained it in this context, but what is it?

Comment: In this have taken mutable array , then as you wanted to randomize your array order. So mutable array has method which is written above will perform this while passing random number on it.

Comment: arc4random() is a function which generates random numbers. Also i have declared as function now please follow in code it is declared now arc4random();

Comment: also where would i declare the path and type of file so that i can use the audio?

Comment: In your code, how you are passing in your array, do the same here also.

Comment: Also i have seen you are extracting path like thatNSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Woof" ofType:@"mp3"]; so try like this below for each file add the path to array

Comment: And then extract path from an array objectatindex:0 in string and do the same how you are doing in your play action method.

Comment: i added an edit, i don't know if you can see it but essentially could i change the names of the sounds to sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4, and so on and then the random number is generated and feeds into the string like this:

NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound%" ofType:@"mp3"];

would that work?

Comment: Yes it will random your string, so on the basis of that you can play your song, And also let me know where you have been stucked. Also if you directly execute above my code you will get to know it will random each time when it execute.